# How would you finger this piano phrase?

Tags: piano, technique, fingering

[image: phrase in question]

Looking at the second half of the 4th beat, I'm curious how someone might recommend fingering the right hand of this particular phrase. The written fingerings are my best guesses. The positions feel comfortable and seem like they would work at a higher speed (the piece calls for q = 80). The (1 4)-5-(1 4)-2-3 fingering seems more natural, but (1 3)-4-(1 3)-2-3 variation takes advantage of the strength of the 3rd finger.

I understand that fingering is subjective to personal preference, hand size, etc., but there are also well-established patterns for certain phrases that tend to work better. Is there any sort of precedence in the piano literature with a similar sort of phrase or fingering that I could reference? This piece itself is not part of the standard repertoire, so there aren't really other sources to consult.

Answer (score 1):

Play the last note (F) of the middle part with your left hand. That's much easier than growing an extra finger on your right hand! You could play all of the last two or three notes (Eb Eb F) with the LH if you prefer.

Your pencil markings seem to "run out of fingers" with your right hand before you get to the end of the bar. Try 5/1 (or 5/2, but I would prefer 5/1) on the third beat, not 4/1.

Comment: Curiously enough, after I took that photo, I changed the fingering on beat three so 5 would end up on that Db. I had been thinking about pulling the Eb, and F into the left hand as well, but not the other Eb. That seems like it may allow the RH to be in a better position to play beat 4.

Answer (score 0):

If the tied over Db is played with the ring finger (4), there are enough fingers left for the rest of the bar.